# Installing some Module ------- Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK

Tags: perl, module

When I try install some Modules like `GD` I got this error message. Seems that the option `installdirs` in `Build.PL` is no more recognized.

Anyone could help me please?

```
.
.
.
DEL(17/18): /home/uce/.cpan/build/Moo-2.001001-dPJd5X.yml 
DEL(18/18): /home/uce/.cpan/build/Array-Compare-2.11-6HHi2g.yml 
Configuring L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz with Build.PL
Configuring for libgd version 2.1.1-dev@.
Checking for stray libgd header files...none found.

Unknown option: installdirs
Usage: perl Build.PL [options]

Configure GD module.

 Options:
     -options       "JPEG,FT,PNG,GIF,XPM,ANIMGIF"   feature options, separated by commas
     -lib_gd_path   path            path to libgd
     -lib_ft_path   path            path to Freetype library
     -lib_png_path  path            path to libpng
     -lib_jpeg_path path            path to libjpeg
     -lib_xpm_path  path            path to libxpm
     -lib_zlib_path path            path to libpng
     -ignore_missing_gd             Ignore missing or old libgd installations and try to compile anyway

If no options are passed on the command line.  The program will
attempt to autoconfigure itself with the gdlib-config program (present
in GD versions 2.0.27 or later).  Otherwise it will prompt for these
values interactively.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/local/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
  LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz
  /usr/local/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz                           : writemakefile NO '/usr/local/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site' returned status 512
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami How can I do that?

Comment: cpan install Module::Build - Module::Build is up to date (0.4218)

Comment: ug, it's because GD's Build.PL doesn't pass its options to Module::Build as per convention.